# hud-service is using 800 MB, is this necessary?

Tags: hud

hud-service in system monitor is currently using 800 MB of memory. Is this normal? What is it for? Is there a way I can reduce it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sadly this is [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/987060) which is being looked at and a fix will hopefully be available soon in the software updates...

You could kill the hud-service in the system monitor and recover all the memory it was using, plus it will restart the service:

```
killall -9 hud-service
```

Comment: still a bug? chewing 40% in a 1G memory Asus. this fixed it though :)

Comment: 3 years later and still a bug... this fixed the issue though. Thanks!